# CipherOutputStream does not flush data to socket output stream

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, outputstream

So my code should send float to the server and receive integer from it. But it does not. Apparently some problem with flush method, it seems the data isn`t going to the server. In my code socket.output()/input() and _output/_input returns CipherStreams wrapped into DataStreams for an established connection. safeInstance method establishing connection and creating Ciphers. OuputStream in the client and InputStream in the server contains an int(0) and UTF string with client hex version of public key. Secret Keys are identical. Is there some solution without closing stream after sending data (or a way to renew it after close)? Cipher using AES.

On the client side we have

```
try {
    UtilDHSocket socket = UtilDHSocket.safeInstance(0);
    socket.output().writeFloat(1.0F);
    socket.output().flush();
    int answer = socket.input().readInt();
    socket.input().close();
    socket.output().close();
    socket.close();
    return answer == 200;
} catch(Exception ex) {
    error(ex);
    return false;
}
```

And something like that on the server side

```
try {
    float clientVersion = _input.readFloat();
    if(clientVersion == Main._version) {
        _output.writeInt(200);
    } else {
        _output.writeInt(418);
    }
    _output.flush();
    _input.close();
    _output.close();
    _client.close();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    warning("Unable to process packet form ",this._client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
    debug(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing either the input stream or the output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket. You therefore have two redundant closes. Remove the closure of the input stream and the socket. Then the closure of the output stream can do what it needs to do to the stream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it even can't reach the close statement. It stuck at input.read() statement.

Comment: You didn't mention 'stuck at `input.read()`' in your question, and you don't mention whether you've actually *tried* this suggestion, *at both ends.*